# Define boost variant type to pass explicitly empty values

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I want to have `boost::variant` with empty state. So I define a `boost::variant` with `boost::blank` as the first alternative. But then I want to pass this as function parameter:

```
void f(Variant v);
...
void g()
{
   f(boost::blank{});
}
```

It does not look nice due to braces. Seem to be better if it accepted `boost::none`:

```
void g()
{
   f(boost::none);
}
```

But I don't think I have seen `boost::variant<boost::none_t, ...>` anywhere. `boost::none_t` is a satellite of `boost::optional`. Is it fine to use with `boost::variant`?

Comment: So you really want an OptionalVariant.

Comment: @rturrado that's not the same and also can be less efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just default construct, which will initialize the first element type.

Alternatively you can define your own constant of type `boost::blank`:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eqMELlFe6gTOjviT)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Variant = boost::variant<
    boost::blank,
    int,
    std::string>;

void foo(Variant v = {}) {
    std::cout << "foo: " << v.which() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    foo({});
    foo(Variant{});
    foo(boost::blank{});
    
    static constexpr boost::blank blank;
    foo(blank);
    
    foo(42);
    foo("LtUaE");
}
```

Prints

```
foo: 0
foo: 0
foo: 0
foo: 0
foo: 0
foo: 1
foo: 2
```